# Can not input data into password field with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a python signup script with selenium to access a site and signuo to it, the user can add their specifications from the terminal. I tested the script on one of my django sites, the script succeeds in adding the first and last name but gets errors when trying to add the password.

```
'''INSTALL CHROME DRIVER ONLINE AND COPY THE PATH TO THE chrome_path'''


import time

import random

from chromedriver_py import binary_path

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

number_of_signups = 0


'''TO RANDOMLY GENERATE USERNAMES'''
def gen_rand_un():
    un = "16JE00"
    un += str(random.randint(0, 9)) + str(random.randint(0, 9)) + str(random.randint(0, 9)) + str(random.randint(0, 9))
    return un

'''You would have to know the ELEMENT ID or element NAME of the inputs, this can be gotten by inspecting elements'''
def main(site, firstName, lastName, el, password):
    while 1:
            un = gen_rand_un()

            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=binary_path), options=options)

            url = site

            driver.get(url)
            
            if firstName == "" or lastName == "":
                pass            
            else:
                fname = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"first_name")
                fname.send_keys(firstName)

                lname = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"last_name")
                lname.send_keys(lastName)

            # username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
            # if username:     
            #     username.send_keys(un)
            # else:
            #     pass

            password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password1")
            password.send_keys(password)

            re_password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password2")
            re_password.send_keys(password)

            email = driver.find_element(By.name, "email")
            if email:
                if el == '':
                    email.send_keys("hacker" + un + "@gmail.com")
                else:
                    email.send_keys(el)
            else:
                pass

            # outside = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "log")
            # if outside:
            #     outside.click()
            # else:
            #     pass
            
            btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")
            btn.click()

            #Waiting to get registered:
            time.sleep(5)

            driver.quit()
            
            number_of_signups += 1
            print("No. of Signups so far: {}".format(number_of_signups))

            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Input info here:")
    site = input("input site url here: ")
    firstName = input("input first name if needed: ")
    lastName = input("input last name if needed: ")
    email = input("input email if needed: ")
    password = str(input("Input the password: "))
    


    main(site, firstName, lastName, email, password)
```

the error i get from the terminal is:

```
Input info here:
input site url here: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
input first name if needed: malik
input last name if needed: kamil
input email if needed: ml@aol.com
Input the password: 0987654321qQ

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55176/devtools/browser/3af7b233-5460-4af4-937a-f3da8c701157
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MAIN_new\signup script.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(site, firstName, lastName, email, password)
  File "c:\Users\MAIN_new\signup script.py", line 54, in main
    password.send_keys(password)
  File "C:\Users\MAIN_new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {"text": "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), "value": keys_to_typing(value)}
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MAIN_new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 137, in keys_to_typing
    characters.extend(val)
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully what you are assigning in your code. You are overwriting the parameter `password` by assigning the element you are trying to find with selenium.

```py
def main(site, firstName, lastName, el, password):
    # doing stuff ...
    password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password1")
    password.send_keys(password)
    # more stuff ...
```

Your parameter password is being overwritten by the `driver.find_element()` method, so when you want to `password.send_keys()` to the element, you are not passing the string password but the element you found with selenium. Just rename it

```py
password_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password1")
password_element.send_keys(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error happens at the call of

```
password.send_keys(password)
```

we need to find out what's wrong with that. The error suggests that you wanted to iterate some elements, but you had an object instead. This is a very strange error in view of the fact that you used `find_element` which returns a single object and tried to perform a similar action to the one you executed for other fields successfully.

`password` was a parameter you received by the method and your code tries to override it. Use a different variable for your password field instead. If the problem persists even after this, read on.

You will also need to be very careful when you define how you want to find your element. Make sure that `password1` and `password2` respectively are indeed the correct **names** of the fields you search for.